# Jwt token authentication Invalid token with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, jwt, token

I'm working with NodeJs with token authentication using jwt(jsonwebtoken).

I'm trying to add the authentication to an endpoint in order to verify if the token provided was correct,
the next are my methods:

```
async function create(req, res) {
  try {
    const token = req.headers["access-token"];
    console.log("token:" + token);
    console.log("decodedToken:", req.decoded);
    return res.status(200).send(req.body.comments);
  } catch (error) {}
}

 async function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
      const tokenHeader = req.headers["access-token"];
      const token = tokenHeader.split(" ")[1];
      console.log("tokenVerify:", tokenHeader.split(" ")[1]);
      console.log("tokenn:", token);

  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ mensaje: "Invalid Token." });
      } else {
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.send({
      mensaje: "No provided token.",
    });
  }
}

module.exports = {
  create,
  verifyToken,
};
```

This is my route code:

```
app.post("/comment/", verifyToken, commentsController.create);
```

But I'm always getting a `Invalid Token.` message.

This is the way how I'm generating the token when the user tries to log into the app:

```
function generateAccessToken(user) {
  return jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: 1440 });
}
```

I'm passing the token through the headers with the next format:

Bearer `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9....` next characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though the problem is that you are not stripping the token out of the header properly.  Here is what you have:

```
async function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.headers["access-token"];
  console.log("tokenVerify:", token.split(" ")[1]);

  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
```

Note that you are stripping out the token in the console.log, but not in the actual code.  So, here is what you need:

```
async function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  const tokenHeader = req.headers["access-token"];
  const token = tokenHeader.split(" ")[1]);
  console.log("tokenVerify:", token);

  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: What token value is being logged in the verify method and what value is being logged when you first create the token?

Comment: Yes, you are right with the first answer.My real error was: TokenExpiredError: jwt expired